# How to move the cursor to next UITextField programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am developing an application where I am creating some `UITextField` programmatically, and I allow a maximum 1 character in the `UITextField`.

This is working perfectly.

But after writing the character, the user has to again tap in the next `UITextField` to present the keyboard

After typing 1 character the cursor should automatically move to next `UITextField`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Catch the delegate that informs you your textfield has been changed. Check if the new length is 1. If it is, call `becomeFirstResponder` on the next field.

Comment: `[textField becomeFirstResponder]`

Answer (score 4):

I have found this approach..

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if(textField == textField1)
    {
        if (textField1.text.length > 0  && range.length == 0 )
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else {
            [textField1 setText:newString];
            [textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
            return YES;
        }
    }
    else if(textField == textField2)
    {
        if (textField2.text.length > 0  && range.length == 0 )
        {
            return NO;
        }else {
            [textField2 setText:newString];
            [textField3 becomeFirstResponder];
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

We can do it in another way...
Declare this line in viewDidLoad and that method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(endEditingTextField:) name:@"UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification" object:txtfield1];

- (void) endEditingTextField:(NSNotification *)note {
    if ([[txtfield1 text] length] > 0)
    {
        [txtfield1 resignFirstResponder];
        [txtfield2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

Above solution did not work. This solution does work for me:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if(firstCodeField == textField){
        [firstCodeField setText:newString];
        [secondCodeField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if(secondCodeField == textField){
        [secondCodeField setText:newString];
        [thirdCodeField becomeFirstResponder];
    }

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 1) ? NO : YES;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in 3 simple steps:

1. The current text field should resign for the cursor.
2. Calculate the following text field
3. Make the following text field gain the cursor.

In code:

```
if ([currentTextFieldWithCursor canResignFirstResponder]) [currentTextFieldWithCursor resignFirstResponder];
UITextField *followingTextField = // just get it!
if ([followingTextField canBecomeFirstResponder]) [followingTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

just set

> UITextFieldDelegate

and past this method in your .m file. it will works For OTP text Boxes.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if(_txt1 == textField){
        if ([_txt1.text length] == 0) {
             [_txt1 setText:newString];
               [_txt2 becomeFirstResponder ];
        }

    }
    if(_txt2 == textField){

        if ([_txt2.text length] == 0) {
              [_txt2 setText:newString];
              [_txt3 becomeFirstResponder];
        }

    }

    if(_txt3 == textField){

         if ([_txt3.text length] == 0) {
              [_txt3 setText:newString];
               [_txt4 becomeFirstResponder];
         }

    }

    if(_txt4 == textField){

        if ([_txt4.text length] == 0) {
             [_txt4 setText:newString];
        }

    }

    NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
    return (newLength > 1 && newLength == 2) ? NO : YES;
}
```

Hope this work for anyone. :)

Answer (score 0):

you've to just use

```
[textField'sName becomeFirstResponder];
```